# Nvidia graphics driver crashes in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia, graphics, 18.04

Few days ago I upgraded my laptop from ubuntu 17.10 to ubuntu 18.04. In my laptop it has two graphic controllers(intel and Nvidia). Normally I have been using `Nvidia X server` tool for switching between them.

When I'm upgrading from 17.10 to 18.04 it was using `Nvidia` graphics mode and not any of problems occurred during upgrade and successfully booted into ubuntu 18.04.

But my question is, after upgrade, I selected Intel graphics mode and now I can't boot my computer, because it is looping with an error message, where after the boot screen with ubuntu logo appears.

Note that I can't even log into tty sessions and fail safe graphics modes also didn't work.

So can anyone help me to resolve this error without reinstalling the entire operating system??

Comment: why did you upgraded?! even canonical said that his upgrade tool was buggy. the only thing i can tell is to use a pendrive and mount the partition to recompile the kernel(read archlinux wiki)… or at least save your data, maybe you can edit the nvidia config to switch again to nvidia instead of Intel... who knows?, just try with a live session

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue and I haven't found a permanent solution, although you can switch back to the nvidia profile via tty.

After you boot and before you log in with gdm switch to *tty you can switch the profile back to nvidia via this command:

```
sudo prime-select nvidia
```

Then reboot and login should work like before.

On my laptop this was <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>

Comment: Yeah, this is acceptable, but the problem is I even cannot login to tty, because it is keep resetting the screen

Answer (score 0):

I have had a lot of problems , and the best solution is the one I found in:  https://medium.com/@emtudo/ubuntu-18-04-travamento-com-placa-nvidia-3720dfe7410a
(Though I have to start session through recovery mode afterwards)